# How to pad date-time string with '0' to sort correctly in pandas

Tags: python, string, datetime, pandas, format

**What is the best way to pad all date-time strings in a dataframe with 0s**, so that for example, `1/2/2016 8:42` becomes `01/02/2016 08:42`?

The strings are usually in the format `d/m/yyyy h:mm` but in some cases may instead be "MAX" or "MIN".

**I need to pad the zeros so that sorting on the timestamp is correct.**

Although converting the strings to a `datetime` object would be ideal, this cannot be done due to other parts of the code which expect it to be a string.

My current implementation uses `strptime` and `strftime`:

```
bad = '1/2/2016 8:42'
good = '01/02/2016 08:42'
df = pandas.DataFrame({'Timestamp':[bad,good], 'Foo':[42,117]})

print(df)

try:
    # Convert timestamp to have leading zeros to allow for correct sorting, so e.g. 8:42 converts to 08:42
    df['Timestamp'] = df['Timestamp'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M").strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"))
except ValueError:  # Timestamp is MAX/MIN
    pass

print(df)
```

Which outputs:

```
   Other         Timestamp
0     27     1/2/2016 8:42
1     59  01/02/2016 08:42

   Other         Timestamp
0     27  01/02/2016 08:42
1     59  01/02/2016 08:42
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Using Pandas series, this code works:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd


bad = '1/2/2016 8:42'
good = '01/02/2016 08:42'
data = {}
data['Timestamp'] = bad
data = pd.Series(data)
print(data)

try:
    # Convert timestamp to have leading zeros to allow for correct sorting
    # so e.g. 8:42 converts to 08:42
    data['Timestamp'] = datetime.strptime(data['Timestamp'], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M').strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
except ValueError:
    # Timestamp is MAX/MIN
    pass

print(data)
assert good == data['Timestamp']
```

This will print:

```
Timestamp    1/2/2016 8:42
dtype: object
Timestamp    01/02/2016 08:42
dtype: object
```

---

You can get rid of the `apply` function, you will end on `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'apply'`:

```
try:
    data['Timestamp'] = datetime.strptime(data['Timestamp'], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M').strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Comment: Using this gives `TypeError: must be string, not Series`, which I assume would be because it's a DataFrame object, not a single string. Updated the question to make this more clear.

Comment: I tried with Pandas series with the code I updated. Can you post your data setup to try with real data?

Comment: `data` in this case is a DataFrame containing several series, not a single series. I'll update the question with a better code example.

Comment: I could have missed something, but what you posted seems good, is not it?

Comment: I'm new to Python, so I thought there might be a better or more 'pythonic' way to do it. Converting to a datetime object and back with the chained strptime/strftime purely to pad with zeros seems inefficient.